# How can I create a SUM function in sheets that keeps adding cells?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheets where I keep the accounting and which contains in a specific row the profit of the products I ship. I'd like to create a sparkline of the money that I win and how it starts to sum up. It does look pretty basic, but the problem is that I do not know how to put the data so as to create the sparkline graphic.
To explain it, I have the first product in a specific cell, and two cells below I have the second one and so on and so on. When I create de SUM function for the data I start:

`=SUM(J10) =SUM(J10:J12) =SUM(J10:J14) And so on`

That's were the problem is, I don't know how to make a formula that will automate this. I wish I could do something like "=SUM(J10:J(10+3 * 'some number')" but it doesn't work.
Thanks if anybody takes the time to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approachs.

If 'some number' is in a cell, the formula is `=SUM(OFFSET($J$10,,,L10,1))` (e.g M10)

To sum column J based on another column, use  `=SUM(OFFSET($J$10,,,COUNTA(I:I)-1,1))` (e.g M17)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your first cell,

```
=SUM(J$10:j10)
```

then drag the cell down from the bottom right-hand corner of the first cell.  You'll know you can drag it down when you see a small plus symbol for your mouse cursor "+".

Comment: It wouldn't work, the J$10 made that cell unchangeable for the next ones but whenever I continued the formula it went from J10 to J11 to J12 and so on, it had to go from J10 to J13 to J16... Thanks anyway, the dollar symbol helped me understand more.